Split pandas column and create new columns that has the count of those split values
I have an excel file in which one of the columns has multiple values seperated by a comma (please see the attached image)

For the StuType column, the numbers go all the way from 1 to 13 including some blank rows (as can be seen in ResponseID = 8538 and 8562).
I am reading the file into pandas. The goal is to have 13 different columns with values 0 and 1 in there. My question is very similar to this one, however, both the solutions suggested there do not work for me.
Can someone please help me? Thank you so very much!
Edit: The solution from @ouroboros1 is perfect! There are some issues with my Excel file though (notice, how '5,8' is to the left and '10', '12', etc. are to the right...I fixed that in Excel before running the solutions provided). Once again, thanks a lot for everyone's help!

If you get KeyError: 'StuType' after trying the answer by @AndrejKesely, then evidently your df does not contain a column StuType. Please update your Q with your df as text, not an image. Use df.to_dict() and post between triple backticks (```).

Edit: all credits to @mozway for the refactored solution (see this comment).

Here's an approach with Series.str.get_dummies:
df = (
    df.join(
        df.pop('StuType')
        .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
        .rename(columns=int)
        .reindex(range(1, 14), axis=1, fill_value=0)
    )
)

Output
    Response  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
0       8524  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0
1       8528  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0
2       8538  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
3       8548  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0
4       8558  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
5       8568  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
6       8578  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0
7       8588  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
8       8598  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
9       8608  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
10      8618  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
11      8628  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
12      8638  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1   1   0   0

Explanation

Use df.pop to work with df['StuType'], while dropping it from df, and apply Series.str.get_dummies with `sep=',').
Cast string column names of the resulting df to int with df.rename.
Chain df.reindex to add columns (axis=1) within range(1, 14) that are not yet present, populating NaN values with 0 by setting fill_value=0.
Join to original df (now without 'StuType' column) with df.join.

If for some reason you want to keep the original df intact (df.pop will alter it), you can use pd.concat instead of df.pop + df.join:
out = (
    pd.concat([
        df['Response'],
        (
            df['StuType']
            .str.get_dummies(sep=',')
            .rename(columns=int)
            .reindex(range(1, 14), axis=1, fill_value=0)
        )
    ], axis=1)
)


Solution before refactoring suggested by @mozway (edited):
Here's an approach with pd.get_dummies:
out = (
    pd.concat([
        df['Response'],
        (
            pd.get_dummies(df['StuType'].str.split(',').explode())
            .rename(columns=int)
            .groupby(level=0).sum()
            .reindex(range(1,14), axis=1, fill_value=0)
        )
    ], axis=1)
)

# same output

Data used
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Response': {0: 8524, 1: 8528, 2: 8538, 3: 8548, 4: 8558, 5: 8568, 6: 8578, 
                     7: 8588, 8: 8598, 9: 8608, 10: 8618, 11: 8628, 12: 8638}, 
        'StuType': {0: '5,8', 1: '10', 2: '12', 3: '2,5,10', 4: '13', 5: np.nan, 
                    6: '7', 7: '12', 8: '5', 9: '13', 10: '13', 11: np.nan, 
                    12: '5,8,10,11'}
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

    Response    StuType
0       8524        5,8
1       8528         10
2       8538         12
3       8548     2,5,10
4       8558         13
5       8568        NaN
6       8578          7
7       8588         12
8       8598          5
9       8608         13
10      8618         13
11      8628        NaN
12      8638  5,8,10,11


Use str.get_dummies instead of get_dummies and you won't have to split ;)

@mozway: excellent point. I’ll be updating that first thing tomorrow morning. Thanks!

I'd use df = df.join(df.pop('StuType').str.get_dummies(sep=',').rename(columns=int).reindex(columns=range(1,14), fill_value=0))

@mozway: updated. Thanks again. Odd misalignment, incidentally, though irrelevant here, that Series.str.get_dummies gets you integers (no dtype parameter either), while pd.get_dummies defaults to bool since pd 2.0.x.

Thanks a lot @mozway for suggesting a simpler solution!

Thanks a lot @ouroboros1...your help is very much appreciated! Thank you also for taking the time to provide the detailed explanation :)

If you input dataframe is:
    Response    StuType
0       8524        5,8
1       8528         10
2       8538         12
3       8548     2,5,10
4       8558         13
5       8568       None
6       8578          7
7       8588         12
8       8598          5
9       8608         13
10      8618         13
11      8628       None
12      8638  5,8,10,11

Then you can try:
df["StuType"] = df["StuType"].fillna("").str.split(r"\s*,\s*", regex=True)

df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            [{int(x): 1 for x in t if x} for t in df.pop("StuType")], index=df.index
        )
        .reindex(columns=range(1, 14))
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

print(df)

Prints:
    Response  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
0       8524  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0
1       8528  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0
2       8538  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
3       8548  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0
4       8558  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
5       8568  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
6       8578  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0
7       8588  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
8       8598  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
9       8608  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
10      8618  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1
11      8628  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
12      8638  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1   1   0   0


Hi Andrej,
Thank you for the quick response!  I am getting the error -- KeyError: 'StuType'

pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        df['StuType'].apply(
            lambda x: {i:int(str(i) in str(x).split(',')) for i in range(1,14)}
            )
        )
    )


This fails when df['StuType'] has NaN values (cf. df constructors in the other answers), raising AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'. str(x).split(',') will avoid it. Also, the outer str() turns the bools to strings (e.g., 'True' instead of True). Together suggesting: {i:str(i) in str(x).split(',') for i in range(1,14)}.

Are you looking for something like this?
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
Response  StuType
8524  5,8
8528  10
1530  12
8532  2,5,10
8533  13
8538    
8539  7
8545  12
8547  6
1550  12
8555  5
8556  13
8557  13
1562    
8563  5,8,10,11
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=r"\s+")

df['StuType'] = df['StuType'].str.split(',')

df = df.explode('StuType') \
       .pivot_table(index='Response', 
                    columns='StuType', 
                    aggfunc='size', 
                    fill_value=0) \
       .reindex(columns=range(1, 14), 
                index=df['Response'], 
                fill_value=0)

print(df.sort_index().head(5))

StuType   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
Response                                           
1530      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
1550      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0
1562      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0
8524      0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0
8528      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0


Note that the result of this will not include 'Response' values where df['StuType'].isna(), namely [8538, 1562]. I suppose that can be remedied by chaining .reindex(df['Response'], fill_value=0), which will incidentally restore the original order.

@ouroboros1 Yes, that's a good way of getting the complete set of 'Response' observations. Thanks.
